# jQuery clickable seek bar for SoundManager2 mp3 player

Tags: jquery, soundmanager2

I am trying to ad a clickable or dragable seek bar for a soundmanager2 mp3 player. Does anyone notice what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

```
whileplaying:function(){
duration = this.duration;
pos = this.position;
songPosition = (pos/duration)*100;

$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar( "option", "value", songPosition);

$( "#progressbar" ).click(function(e) {
var playingSound = soundManager.getSoundById(_.keys(soundManager.sounds)[0]),
x               = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left,
width           = $(this).width(),
duration        = playingSound.durationEstimate;
playingSound.setPosition((x / width) * duration);
});

$( "#progressbar" ).mouseover(function(){
$(this).css("cursor","pointer");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the whole code out of whileplaying :function() { } because every time when you are calling setPosition, the song position changes but you are not updating the "value" of progressbar in $( "#progressbar" ).click(function(e){ }); function and also whileplaying function is called again and again which sets which sets the "value" to songPosition (that is same as before) when song is playing

try updating value in $( "#progressbar" ).click(function(e) { //update value here also });

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before remove the click events out of the whileplaying function. In fact, you should really put anything (other than maybe visual updates / timestamp updates) in there.

You can simply call var s = soundManager.getSoundById($name) to get the sound object and from there you can use s.setPosition();

I suggest something along the lines of:

```
selectTime.click(function(e){
s = soundManager.getSoundById($name);
var posX = selectTime.offset().left;
var pos = Math.min(Math.max((e.pageX - posX) / selectTime.width() * 100, 0), s.duration);
if(!isNaN(pos))
s.setPosition(Math.round(pos*s.duration/100));
});
```

Make sure you use the flash player, its currently still the best way to use the setPosition function.